# How to access image style url from jQuery code?

Tags: javascript

`image_style_url()` generates proper links, but sadly it's only a PHP function.

Let's assume I want to substitute file icon with preview image on hover:

```
(function($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.ImagePreview = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $('.form-managed-file', context).on('hover', function(){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
      });


    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Not the smartest code in the world, but simple, works and illustrates my example. Now, it will show image in the resolution user uploaded. But I need a thumbnail. It's a built in style so I don't need to test if it exists, but I do need valid security token and I need to respect all the Drupal file system settings, just like `image_style_url()` does. How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Note: In my case both input and output need to happen on jQuery side, as the image may not even be on the server when page is rendered.

Comment: I don't have time to write this in as an answer, so I'll just leave a comment - but could you use a menu callback and an AJAX request? Or is that out of the scope of your requirements?

Comment: @Chapabu if Drupal does not provide this functionality out of the box, I will have to do just that. But I hope there is built-in function and I simply cannot find it. Either way I think it's worth to have this figured out and posted for future visitors.

Comment: There a pretty good answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68099/how-to-get-images-into-a-slideshow-via-json-javascript-with-new-itok) from MPD that should answer your question actually! If not, you should at least be able to modify it :-)

Comment: @Mołot Do you need a single style, or any style?  I have another approach for single styles, too.

Comment: @MPD specifically I need thumbnail style. Or any other one, but I can hard code it all right.

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate as I want URL provided from javascript side, not from PHP side. So any answer that will be OK there will be at least incomplete here, even if relevant and helpful. I'll be happy if it can be closed as a duplicate of a question that asks for both in put and output in javascript side. Editing [How to get images into a slideshow via json javascript with new itok](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/68129/16495) to meet my needs would be a radical change.

Answer (score 4):

For a single image style, I tack it on as a data attribute to the image.  Then in my JS, I use that.

This is how I handle retina images, using src switching (edited to just show the relevant portions):

```
function MYTHEME_image_style($variables) {
  // ...

  if (in_array($variables['style_name'] . '_2x', array_keys(image_styles())) {
    $variables['data-retina'] = image_style_url($variables['style_name'] . '_2x', $path);
  }

  return theme('image', $variables);
}

/**
 * Implements theme_image().
 */
function MYTHEME_image($variables) {
  // ...

  if (isset($variables['data-retina'])) {
    $attributes['data-retina'] = file_create_url($variables['data-retina']);
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```

This in the JS (again, lifted and edited):

```
$('img').each(function (i, img) {
  var $img = $(img);

  if ($img.data('retina')) {
    $img.data('src', img.src);
    img.src = $img.data('retina');
  }
});
```

The key is to generate the style URL on the server side, so that the URL includes the itok and that all hooks get fired to allow modules like CDN to work.  You just need to figure out the proper place to do it from.  In your case, I suspect you may need to do it from a `theme_field`.